# how to play sound after delay in xcode

Tags: xcode, ios4

How can I play sound automatically after 2 seconds?

Answer (score 3):

you would use a timer for that

```
- (void)playSomeSound:(NSTimer *)timer {
    // Your sound playing code goes here
}

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(playSomeSound:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```